# How to change a variable based on current time in python?

Tags: python, variables, time

I want to reset a variable to 0 once it is the next day (i.e. when time = 00:00:00). How do I do that?

Comment: `if time == 00:00:00: variable = 0`

Answer (score 1):

Try using `datetime` :

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
if ( now.hour == 0 and now.minute == 0 and now.secound == 0 ) :
    # Do something
```